# How to evaluate integral with radian limits?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/6} \csc \theta \cot \theta\, d\theta $$

Comment: $\int \csc \theta \cot \theta \, d\theta=-\csc \theta+C$.

Comment: If you are having trouble formatting, then you might want to read [this MathJaX tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?lq=1).

Comment: $$\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/6} \csc \theta \cot \theta\, d\theta=\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/6}\frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin^2(\theta)}\,d\theta$$
Do a $u$-substitution where $u=\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: Can you walk me through what you mean Eli?

Comment: Yeah sure give me a minute and I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/6} \csc \theta \cot \theta\, d\theta=\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/6}\frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin^2(\theta)}\,d\theta$$
Do a $u$-substitution for $u=\sin(\theta)$. Therefore, $du=cos(\theta)\,d\theta, d\theta=\frac{du}{\cos(\theta)}.$ Substitute back in to get:
$$\int\frac{\cos(\theta)}{u^2}\frac{du}{\cos(\theta)}=\int\frac{1}{u^2}\,du=-\frac{1}{u}$$
Re-substituting your original $u$-substitution gives $$-\frac{1}{sin(\theta)}\bigg|_{\pi/3}^{\pi/6}=-2+\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Comment: Ok, I think I'm starting to get it (though taking Precalculus online is still hurting me on all the sin/cos/tan stuff). How would this work if I was evaluating from 0 to 1 the integral of `(1+x^2)^2 dx` ? I would I believe take `(1+x^2)` as my u, giving me 2x as my du, but then what?

Comment: No, in that case just expand $(1+x^2)^2$ to get a polynomial that you can integrate using the reverse-power rule (see more here: [Paul's Online Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/IndefiniteIntegrals.aspx)). This is purely calculus though, so I'm not sure why you're learning it in a precalculus class. Be careful of just learning the methods without really understanding the concept of what integrals & derivatives are, and the relationship between them. Good luck!

Comment: Ok, so in my second example I get `(1+x^2)^2 = x^4+2x^2+1` which would be `\int_0^1(x^4+2x^2+1)dx` So the derivative (evaluated answer?) would be...?

Comment: First of all, this is a different question :p Secondly, wrap equations with dollar signs to render them nicely. Thirdly, did you check out that link from my answer? It has the answer to your question, and if you skip ahead a little you'll find how to evaluate the definite integral (where you know the bounds; in this case, the bounds are $x\in[0, 1]$).

Comment: @EliBerkowitz you commited a sign fault in the very end.

Comment: @GuilhermeThompson oops - thanks! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int^{\pi/6}_{\pi/3}\csc\theta\cot\theta d\theta=[\csc\theta]^{\pi/6}_{\pi/3}$$
$$=\csc \frac{\pi}{6}-\csc\frac{\pi}{3}$$
$$=2-\frac{2}{\sqrt3}$$
$$=\frac{6-2\sqrt3}{3}$$

If you prefer using degrees over radians, you can convert the radians into degrees by using $$deg=\frac{rad\times180}{\pi}$$

Comment: No, $\int \csc\theta\cot \theta\, d\theta =-\csc\theta+C\neq \csc\theta+C$.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Just swap the order of the antiderivatives then.

Answer (score 0):

In the integral $$\int_{\frac{\pi }{3}}^{\frac{\pi }{6}} \cot (\theta ) \csc (\theta ) \, d\theta = \int_{\frac{\pi }{3}}^{\frac{\pi }{6}} \dfrac{1}{\sin(\theta)} \dfrac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} \, d\theta, $$ we substitute $\sin (\theta) \mapsto u$  and $d\theta \cos (\theta ) \mapsto du$. The integration limits also are changed. So we write
$$\int_{\sin(\frac{\pi }{3})}^{\sin(\frac{\pi }{6})} \dfrac{du}{u^2}  = - \dfrac{1}{u} \Big|_{\sqrt{3}/2}^{1/2}= -2- \left(-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \right) = \frac{2}{3}\left(1-\sqrt{3} \right)  $$